# Using the bms-push cordova plugin, tapping on a notification received on Android do not launch the app

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I've recently updated to the latest version of the [bms-push](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push) cordova plugin.

Seems like when we now receive a notification on an Android device, tapping on the notification does not launch the app anymore.

Is it the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a change in the native Android's manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushNotificationHandler" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joe. It does not exactly work as I would have expected. Indeed, when the app is in the background and a push is received, clicking on the notification restarts the app. It does not bring it out from its background state as it was the case before.

Comment: I've been able to recreate and currently in discussion with the development team.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Seems like adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the main activity does the trick, but I would really appreciate a feedback from the dev team

Comment: Hi @JohanMereaux, I will ask them to see if they have any updates. It's good to see you found a solution though.

Comment: Hi @JohanMereaux, they recommended the following: "In the Android manifest file locate `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and replace it with `android:launchMode="singleTask"`"